# kafka consumer not consuming records in server

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

I have created a `java class` for consuming records, I am connected to corresponding servers and everything done, while running this `class` from my local machine its working and able to consume messages, but after maven build getting jar file, I am placing this jar file on my server from there I am running my `java class` , There it is subscribing to the topic successfully, after that not receiving the messages but in local it is subscribing and receiving messages.

Comment: Have you tried producing additional messages to the server while the consumer is running on the server?

Answer (score 0):

In server, kafka server IP is different that is the reason why it is not able to consume messages. After changing kafka server IPs its worked.